# Working of pre-processor C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

```
#define NAME VALUE
```

I know whenever the compiler see this, it would replace NAME with VALUE. But I'm confused about the working of pre-processing directives such as :

```
#define CONFIG_VAR(name, type, value)
```

This does not tell the compiler to replace anything , but I could see statements like

```
CONFIG_VAR(rank, int, 100)
```

which would compile successfully. How does this work ?

Comment: Are you sure that's the entire definition of `CONFIG_VAR`?

Comment: Yes it is the entire definition

Comment: Is there another definition of `CONFIG_VAR` nearby? Maybe after an `#else`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, that would simply do nothing at all. Any arguments, even those that seem like they should give compilation errors, are accepted and the whole macro call is replaced with an empty string.

If, however, you later replace the definition with something like:

```
#define CONFIG_VAR(name, type, value) add_config_var<type>(name, value)
```

it would suddenly do something useful. So, I'd guess that macro is a placeholder for functionality which is not (yet) implemented or not available in that part of the program.

Comment: So until I define that function, its doesnt expand to anything. Still it compiles statements like CONFIG_VAR(rank, int, 100) and 100s of similar other statements which by itself is not a legal C++ code. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You are correct. Macros aren't anything like other code. They are simply rules for text substitution performed before most stages of compilation and don't at all follow most rules of the language.

Answer (score 2):

When you say:

```
#define FOO BAR
```

what the preprocessor does is to replace each time after this it sees the *text* `FOO` by the text `BAR`, a *macro definition*. The process is called *macro expansion*. This is mostly used to define constants, like:

```
#define N 128
#define MASK (~(1 << 4))
```

It *can* be (ab)used to do very funky stuff, as it knows nothing of expressions, statements, or anything. So:

```
#define CONST (1 + 3 << (x))
```

is actually OK, and will expand to `(1 + 3 << (x))` each time it is seen, *using the current value of `x` each time*. Also gunk like:

```
#define START 5 * (1 +
#define END   + 5)
```

followed by `START 2 + 3 + 4 END` predictably gives `5 * (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +`5)`

There is also the option of defining *macros with parameters*, like:

```
#define BAD_SQUARE(x)  x * x
```

which, if called as `BAD_SQUARE(a)` will expand to `a * a`. But `BAD_SQUARE(a + b)` expands to `a + b * a + b`, which isn't what was intended (presumably...).

This comes from the dark ages of C, today's C/C++ have safer/cleaner mechanisms to get the same result (use `const` in C++, in C it sadly defines a variable, not a real constant; use inline functions  in C/C++ or templates in C++). There is too much code out there that uses this preprocessor usage (and too many fingers who write this way) so it is practically impossible to get rid of this. As a rule of thumb, learn to *read* code using macros, whiel learning to *write* code without them (as far as reasonable, there are times when they come mighty handy...).

Answer (score 1):

This is a macro (more common in C than in C++). According to the definition you provided, the preprocessor will remove occurrences of that "function". A common use-case is usually for logging:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define dprintf(...) printf(...)
#else
#define dprintf(...)    // This will remove dprintf lines
#endif
```

In C++, I believe the general convention is to use inline functions as they provide the same value performance-wise, but are also type checked.

Answer (score 0):

In this case pre-processor simply removes such strings (replaces with nothing). Widely enough used technique.

Here is example where it is important (actually only one of possible usages):

```
#if DEBUG_ON
#define LOG(level, string) SomeLogger(level, string)
#else
#define LOG(level, string)
#endif
```

Probably you should get more familiar with [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).

There is somewhat [close technique (X macro)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) which builds code which handles repeating lists based on defined actions.

Comment: So basically , its useful only when another function is defined to retrieve the information ?

Comment: Indeed macro could be used for lot of things (see links I posted) and sometimes macro could be used just to 'mute' some code fragments. This is like 'smart' replacers (smoewhat close to inline functions but in some aspects more powerful and dangerous).

Answer (score 0):

If this really is the entire macro definition, then it simply defines this function-like macro to expand to **nothing** (an empty string). For example, in the source,

```
CONFIG_VAR(rank, int, 100);
```

will be transformed into

```
;
```